# Docusign Error: Unauthorized on production server

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have an application that uses the DocuSign API (the NodeJS SDK, specifically) and got everything working perfectly on the demo sandbox. The Docusign people certified the app for production.

I followed the "Go Live" documentation and changed the endpoint from `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi` to `https://www.docusign.net/restapi` in my `apiClient.setBasePath()`, however, I'm getting a `USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED` error.

The username and password have been set to the same as on the demo sandbox, so I know they are correct. Also the `IntegratorKey` is the same as the demo sandbox, and after they certified the app, I can now see it in my production account.

[Here is a pastebin of the error](http://pastebin.com/VWTYmLKt)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a baseUrl issue, you should be parsing the `baseUrl` that is returned in the login API and using that as the base for subsequent API requests in production.

In your developer sandbox (ie demo) environment all URLs start with "https://demo.docusign.net/" which is why all your test calls work in demo, in the live production system the account URL will vary based on user and which data center their live production account resides on.

You need to parse the `baseUrl` value that is returned from the [Authentication:login](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) API and use that as the base for subsequent DocuSign API requests, or use the `base_uri` value if using [OAuth](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html).

Comment: I looked through the Nodejs SDK code on github and it looks like it handles that for you. The [documentation states](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.js#L16) that you simply change `demo` to `www` in the `baseUrl` and it handles the `baseUrl` that comes back from the `/v2/login_information` API call from `authApi.login()`. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Also, after spending days trying to get someone at Docusign who knows **anything** about the API, finally someone said that the error is because we have the wrong account. Even though the Business account we signed up with **CLEARLY** stated it had API access **AND** they certified our implementation to go live. They are now telling us that we need to spend at least $2000 per year to get API access!!!! That's over $1600 more than we are paying right now. This is terrible business!!

Comment: DocuSign recently updated it's pricing and packaging and has new packages now, however if you purchased your account before the changes then you shouldn't have to worry.  First I would confirm the `baseUrl` the SDK is assigning and ensure it's a proper production server (like na1, na2, eu, etc).

Comment: So it turns out that the baseUrl is NOT set dynamically with the Nodejs client.  Essentially, I had to set `apiClient.setBasePath('https://na2.docusign.net/restapi');`. I had to log the data being returned in the login function in the source code to get that value. Or you can curl the `/v2/login_information`. Hopefully this helps someone else with this issue.